# Angularjs form $error is not getting updated when the model is updated inside a directive unless the model be cleared

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-forms

I can't figure out what's happening in the following example. I just trying to create my own `required` validation in my own directive where I have an array and I want to make it required (it's a simplification of what I want to do but enough to show the point)

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/gsubiran/p3zxkqwe/3/

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      require: 'ngModel',
      controller: 'myDirectiveController',
      controllerAs: 'D_MD',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$validators.required = function(modelValue) {
          var result = false;
          if (modelValue && modelValue.length > 0)
            result = true;

          return result;
        };
      },
      bindToController: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      template: '(<span>ArrayLength:{{D_MD.ngModel.length}}</span>)<br /><input type=button value="add (inside directive)" ng-click=D_MD.AddElem() /><br /><input value="clear (inside directive)" type=button ng-click=D_MD.Clear() />'
    };   })   .controller('myDirectiveController', [function() {
    var CTX = this;
    //debugger;
    //CTX.ngModel = "pipo";
    CTX.clearModel = function() {
      CTX.ngModel = [];
    };
    CTX.AddElem = function() {
      CTX.ngModel.push({
        Name: 'obj100',
        Value: 100
      });
    };
    CTX.Clear = function() {
      CTX.ngModel = [];
    };   }])   .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var CTX = this;
    CTX.patito = 'donde esta el patito';
    CTX.arrayElements = [];
    CTX.setElements = function() {
      CTX.arrayElements = [{
        Name: 'obj0',
        Value: 0
      }, {
        Name: 'obj1',
        Value: 1
      }, {
        Name: 'obj2',
        Value: 2
      }];
    };
    CTX.clearElements = function() {
      CTX.arrayElements = [];
    };   })
```

When I hit the `add (outside directive)` button, the required works fine,
but when I hit the `add (inside directive)` button I still getting the required error in the form (the form is defined outside directive).

But the more confusing thing for me is the following:

**When I hit the `clear (inside directive)` button after hitting `add (outside directive)` button to make the required error go out, in this case the form is updating and the validation error is showing.**

Why $validations.required is not firing inside the directive when I add new element to array but yes when I clear it?

Any ideas?

******* **UPDATE** *******

It seems to be related with `array.push` if I change array.push with the assignation of new array with wanted elements inside it works ok.
**Still the question why it is happening.**

As workaround I changed in the directive the `AddElem` function in this way:

```
CTX.AddElem = function() {
     CTX.ngModel = CTX.ngModel.concat({
        Name: 'obj100',
        Value: 100
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ngModel` you use here is a JS object. Angular has a reference to that object in its `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` (because angular basically does `$viewValue = $modelValue`). The `$modelValue` is the actual value of the `ngModel`, which, if you change it, will change the `$viewValue` after having run `$validators`.

To know if your `ngModel` has Changed, angular compares the `ngModel.$viewValue` with the `ngModel.$modelValue`. Here, you are doing a `push()` to the `$viewValue` which is updating the `$modelValue` at the same time because they are just references of each other. Therefore, when comparing them, they have the same value ! Which is why angular does not run your `$validator`.

[The docs explain it :](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

> Since ng-model does not do a deep watch, $render() is only invoked if the values of $modelValue and $viewValue are actually different from their previous values. If $modelValue or $viewValue are objects (rather than a string or number) then $render() will not be invoked if you only change a property on the objects.

If I over-simplify angular code, this snippet explains it:

```
var myArray = [];

var ngModel = {
  $viewValue: myArray,
  $modelValue: myArray,
  $validate: function () { console.log('validators updated'); }, // log when validators are updated
}

function $apply() { // the function that is called on the scope
  if (ngModel.$viewValue !== ngModel.$modelValue) {
    ngModel.$viewValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
    ngModel.$validate(); // this will trigger your validator
  } else {
    console.log('value not changed'); // the new value is no different than before, do not call $validate
  }
}

// your push is like doing :
ngModel.$viewValue.push(12); 
$apply(); // will output 'value not changed', because we changed the view value as well as the model value

// whereas your should do:
var newArray = [];
// create a copy of the array (you can use angular.copy)
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(myArray[i]);
}
ngModel.$viewValue.push(12);
ngModel.$viewValue = newArray; // here we clearly update the $viewValue without changing the model value
$apply(); // will output 'validators updated'
```

Of course you are not forced to do an array copy. Instead, you can force the update of your ngModel. This is done by calling `ngModel.$validate();`

One way of doing it would be to add a `forceUpdate()` function in your `scope`, and call it from the controller after you do a `push();`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L7Lxkq1f/

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Great explanation